Creating custom keywords in C++ using libraries
I want to create a keyword that modifies a variable during definition. Similar to how long long var; creates something different than long var;, or static int var; does something special to the variable. The question is: how can I create custom keywords that specifically modify variables during initialization.
A specific example: I currently have a library that adds a custom variable type called uint7 that is 7 bits long, 1 less than a byte. I want to have a keyword to double the size, similar to how the code long long var; creates a variable with double the size of a long variable. Specifically, I want to create a keyword "twin" so that I can use twin uint7 var; to make a 14-bit long variable. The reason I can't just make uint14 is because I want this to work on ALL variables, including int, char, bool, float, uint7, and more.
Please note, the reason I am asking this question is to understand how to create the keywords, not specifically for the uint7 or twin concept.

are you aware of class template and metaprogramming? You can make a template class template<typename T> struct twin{ using type = whatever you want to do with T;}. For instance, look at std::make_unsigned

Pedantic terminology note: "keyword" has a defined meaning in C++. Actual keywords are specified in the language specification and you can't change what they are or add a new one.

To answer the question in the title, you cannot add keywords, those are exclusively defined by the language alone.

"I want to have a keyword to double the size" Why does this need to be a keyword?  Why not just have a type named uint14?  "similar to how the code long long var; creates a variable with double the size of a long variable"  That's an incorrect assumption.

@AviBerger I used the term "keyword" because "int" and "long" are both keywords in C++, and since I am imitating those almost exactly, I thought this was the best term to use.

You cannot achieve exactly twin uint7 var; syntax. You could do twin<uint7> if this is better than just uint14.

If your actual goal is to save memory, this is an XY problem. If you simply define a "7 bit" or a "14 bit" type and use them on your 8 bit micro, they will generally be allocated 1 byte leaving 1 bit unused or 2 bytes leaving 2 bits unused and unusable. (motivated by mention now removed from post about being low on storage.)

"The reason I can't just make uint14 is because I want this to work on ALL variables, including int, char, bool, float, uint7, and more." Why would you want to double the storage used by a bool?

14 bit integer is very strange requirement. Why you are complicating your life? Why you need this strange thing? This smells like XY problem.

@AviBerger The memory was a surface level explanation of the context of the problem. If I was able to figure out how to modify the nature of variable initialization using words before a variable type, I would be using it in more ways than just "twin". The point of the question is not the context, but the method.

@ShieldCat You can't do it that way. What you are actually trying to do is create new variable types. And to do that, you need to create them individually or, if it fits into an appropriate pattern, with a template. (If it was more a matter of providing a new name that something else existing could cover, you could use a typedef.)

The only valid answer to this question is "Submit a proposal to the C++ standards committee".  You are describing something that is not in the C++ language.

You cannot add or change keywords in C++ (or C).
The correct way to manage types is to give them a name. The traditional way is with the typedef keyword, but other methods exist, depending on syntactical needs.
You also cannot change integer sizes directly. You can name things to give them semantic meaning useful to the programmer. For example:
typedef unsigned char  uint7;
typedef unsigned short uint14;



You can do weird stuff if you want to be more specific about how bits are handled, but this is equivalent to redefining an integer type yourself. (And I’m not convinced this is correct anyway, but it was fun to do.)
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma pack(push,1)
#endif
union uint7
{
    unsigned value : 7;
    operator int () const { return value; }
    uint7 operator = ( unsigned value ) { this->value = value; return *this; }
    uint7( unsigned value ) : value{value} { }
}
#ifndef _MSC_VER
__attribute__((packed))
#endif
typedef uint7;
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma pack(pop)
#endif

int main()
{
    uint7 x = 127;
    
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    
    x = x + 1;
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    
    x = x + 1;
    std::cout << x << "\n";
    
    std::cout << "size of uint7 = " << sizeof(uint7) << "\n";
}

$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors -O3 -std=c++17 a.cpp
$ ./a.out 
127
0
1
size of uint7 = 1

Notice, for example, that things like ++x and x += 1 are not defined, because I didn’t add them to the definition of uint7.
(So, don’t do this. Just use the type alias to an extant integer type and be careful how you handle its values.)

Where did you define the addition operator?

I didn’t. + is defined over integers. You can read x = x + 1 as x.operator=(x.operator int()+1)

Remember, the weirdo type does not reduce memory. It is still an eight-bit object!

Is there no way to change the number of bits in an object?

No. Remember, you cannot redefine integer objects to anything other than what the processor gives you. You can certainly reduce the amount of storage you use, but the size of integers is not something you can control. If you have an array of N-bit values, you can always pack them into an array of M=⌈kN/8⌉ bytes.
